# Binding click handler to row item: fire method in model

Tags: javascript, ember.js, dom-events

I'm working on a small sample app to get used to writing Ember apps. I'm pulling a JSON feed of my tweets and displaying them to the page. So that I can work on implementing a model into my code I've added a method called `markAsRead`.

I'd like to bind an event to each row item so that when it's clicked it fires it's own `markAsRead` method. The end goal is to change a class on the row item when that event is triggered. Here's the code I've got so far:

http://andymatthews.net/code/emberTweets/

I know that Ember has it's own way of doing things so I'm really looking for a best practice way to approach this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Andy,

I've reconstructed what you have so far and added in the features you're looking for in this jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ud3323/V4qZC/. Hopefully that clears everything up for you :)

Comment: Interesting...thank you Roy. I'll take your Fiddle and work through it. Appreciate your time.

Comment: No problem. To answer your other 2 questions... The `{{#with content}}` changes the scope to Tweets.TweetItemView.content in that example. `contentBinding="this"` binds the content property on the view created to the content of the current item in the #each iterator.

Comment: Thanks. I have a question about your example too. In the JS portion you say `App.set('tweetsController', Ember.ArrayController.create({`. Is that the same as `App.tweetsController = Ember.ArrayController.create`? If so, why use one over the other?

Comment: No it's not. In such a small app it won't matter, but in larger apps where you have singletons (controllers) binding to or accessing other singletons you can run into some big headaches if you don't use Ember's universal accessors. So, best practice, use them at all times when dealing with singletons and properties on Ember objects.

Comment: You can read a little more about Ember's universal accessors (like `get()` and `set()`) here: [https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/blob/master/packages/ember-metal/docs/NOTES.md](https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/blob/master/packages/ember-metal/docs/NOTES.md)

Answer (score 0):

You should use a view for each row item. something like

```
{{#each Tweets.allTweetsController}}
      {{#view Tweets.TweetItemView contentBinding="this"}}
        {{#with content}}
          <li> {{myTweet}}</li>
        {{/#with}}
      {{#/view}}
{{/#each}}
```

TweetItemView should have a click method which will be triggered each time one is clicked. Because of the contentBinding, you'll have access to the individual tweet in the view as content

Comment: So I'd be defining a view in my JS file correct? I haven't done that just yet so that'll be new to me. In your example above, what does the "with content" part do? Is that setting a scope or something?

Comment: And another question, the contentBinding attribute of the view...is that telling the view to use the content from the "each" iterator?

Comment: The with tag sets the handlebars context - if you left it out the myTweet part would need to be content.myTweet (sine the view tag sets the context to be the embedded view)

Comment: Yes for defining a view in the js file - you could avoid that and use the {{action}} tag instead, but if you want to start manupulating these as objects you'll want the view

Comment: and yeah for the contentbinding - that binds the content attribute to the current object. The current object is the context, and the context is set by the each tag

Answer (score 0):

I'm implementing something similar as I'm working on an open source feed reader for wordpress.  The UI is all Ember.  Check out http://mattkatz.github.com/Wordprss - which has mark as read along with keyboard shortcuts.